# Scrolling of multiple recycler view in an activity. (how to make it smooth)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have 2 recyclerviews in my activity 1st one is horizontally scrollable and the 2nd one is vertically scrollable. (XML code given below)
But the scrolling is not smooth.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:clickable="true"
    >
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarCircularIndetermininatesearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
        android:indeterminateTint="#f44336"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressbacklin"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/videolist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_below="@+id/videolist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        />
        </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressbacklin"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adViewsearch"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBarCircularIndetermininate"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
            android:indeterminateTint="#f44336"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adViewsearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i use

```
setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

for both recycler view.

Any ideas to implement this with a smooth scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How i solved this problem is by using a single Recycler view instead of two and setting up the other (1st recycler view in question) recycler view as first item of it.
Now it works perfect and scrolling smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

Change `ScrollView` to `NestedScrollView`.

In order this to work, you need to have `RecyclerView` with height `wrap_content` inside  `NestedScrollView` and you need to set `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` from code.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44348534/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.